# convert time from server to local time in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, timezone

my server returns date and time formatted as 2014-03-16 07:07:25 
and it is UTC 
i need to convert that date and time returned into the mobile time zone 
any suggestions ?
notice that the plate form is windows phone 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("2014-03-16 07:07:25 UTC");
var localtime = date.ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: how to know the timezoon of the emilator ?

Comment: @user2918388 - If that's important to you, please create a new question rather than asking in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this because I'm not sure about what the Windows Phone 8 API contains.
But doesn't DateTime have a `.ToLocalTime()` method?

IE:

```
var utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
var local = utc.ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: i have string passed from the server should i convert it first to dateand time

Comment: As rnrneverdies said, you can parse a datetime string (Provided it's formatted properly), with `DateTime.Parse` (or `DateTime.TryParse` if you don't want to bother checking the format beforehand).

Comment: how to know the timezoon of the emilator ?